# Serialization and Composition

Tags: java, serialization, composition

Im having a BaseRecord class that represents a DBRecord which implements Serializable ..

I need another DB trigger sortof functionality which would have its own data members=trigger activation event data => which when satisfied would insert a BaseRecord

So my question is

- Should i use composition or inheritance here? I'd go for composition as its better saying TriggerRecord HAS-A BaseRecord i.e to be inserted when trigger activation event occurs..
- 1 more thing is that BaseRecord implements Serializable, and user can depending on mode of operation can modify BaseRecords(eventually DB Records) **AND** modify TriggerRecord so i need methods of both BaseRecords(toString(), getters,setters, and other data modifications) and TriggerRecord(BaseRecords method alongwith trigger activation event data handling methods)

So ..

```
class BaseRecord implements Serializable
{
      ...
      ...
}

class TriggerRecord
{
EventData eventData;        //Non-custom Objects
BaseRecord br;
}
```

So my question

- whether should i use composition in this case?
- and is sending a TriggerRecord ArrayList by network serialization would be achieved automatically as all data members of TriggerRecord are Serializable or do i need to explicitly implement Serializable with SerialVersionUID?

Edit 1:
As of now TriggerRecord has only 1 Custom Object of BaseRecord, possibly adding more .. and essentially TriggerRecord is too another mapped to DB Record that has eventData and a different format for BaseRecord storage because it stores BaseRecords of more than 1 relations ..

and if i extend BaseRecord then i'll have to use super.toString() to access BaseRecord's string representation..
and i just tried with composition of BaseRecord inside a TriggerRecord .. it needs implements Serializable even if all data members are already Serializable .. so asking why is it necessary to explicitly implement Serializable for class that is composed of other Custom objects

Comment: still didnt get the necessity but ok i settled for a solution .. i implemented it for composite object because without that it resulted in NotSerializableException

Answer (score 1):

For your knowledge, in Java:

**Composition** means that one object instance (A) to exist have need to other object instance (A1, A2, A3), e.g.

```
public class Car {

   private Engine engine = null;
   private Body body = null;
   private List<Tyre> tyres = null;
   ...
}
```

If you don't have any of there, you can instance Car object, but it is inconsistent.

**Serialization** is writing an object and its dependent object graph to a stream, i.e.

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/object.ser");
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

out.writeObject(YOUR_OBJECT_INSTANCE);

out.close();
```

If your object doesn't implement `java.io.Serializable` this code throw a `NotSerializableException,` and the same applies to all its non-static and non-transient data members, and so on recursively until closure. Use specified `SerialVersionUID` is better, so  JVM don't calculate it at runtime.

In your case :

> - whether should i use composition in this case?

if you use composition, in your `TriggerRecord` you must implement methods for operations that combine `EventData` and `BaseRecord`.

If `TriggerRecord` has some method in common with `BaseRecord`, please extend it and use override method. You avoid code duplication and inefficiency of your code.

> - and is sending a TriggerRecord ArrayList by network serialization would be achieved automatically as all data members of TriggerRecord
>     are Serializable or do i need to explicitly implement Serializable
>     with SerialVersionUID?

As before, better have own `SerialVersionUID` for each class.

If you add more details, we can help you in some other better ways.

Comment: have a look .. added a few details

Comment: "As before, better have own SerialVersionUID for each class. When you serialize list, map or other composite object," .. so i would need to implement Serializable even if the composite objects already implement it ..?

Comment: Yes, all object must be serializable, otherwise you can have exception or wrong serialization that will bring you dirty or wrong data.

Comment: Yup .. Right after Half n hour after posting the question .. i implemented composition only and proper Serialization! :) .. Anyways Thanks for replying :)